# Does the category of topological symmetric spectra satisfy the monoid axiom ?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, model-categories, stable-homotopy

In the paper "Symmetric spectra"by Hovey, Smith and Shipley, they say that they don't know if the monoid axiom holds for topological symmetric spectra. This paper was written in 1998 so I am wondering what is the situation on this question today.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The monoid axiom for symmetric and orthogonal spectra of spaces is
Proposition 12.5 of Mandell, May, Schwede, and Shipley's paper
``Model categories of diagram spectra''.

Comment: Welcome to Math Overflow, Professor May!

Answer (score 6):

I would look at Stefan Schwede's articles. I think the answer is yes, see page 7 of Schwede and Shipley:
http://www.math.uni-bonn.de/people/schwede/AlgebrasModules.pdf

Perhpas this more explicitly states what you want:
http://arxiv.org/PS_cache/math/pdf/9803/9803002v1.pdf
It even references the paper above.

The dates in the bibliography may be a bit confusing. It becomes less confusing when you realize that Symmetric Spectra had been around for a year or so before the published version appeared. Certainly people in the know, such as hovey, schwede, and shipley, knew about Symmetric Spectra.

If you tried really hard you could probably find seminar talks about such stuff.

Comment: Thank you Sean ! I didn't find an answer to my question in that paper but I learnt a lot reading it.

Comment: I think that Schwede and Shipley have been thinking about this stuff, there maybe something in one of their other articles.